# How to round up to closest .5 using C#

Tags: c#, function, math

Working with a time clocking system a lot of the hours clocked end up looking like this:

0.266666666666.

Now, I want to round up all the numbers to the "next .5 value", such that 0.2666666666 becomes 0.5.

Examples:

```
1.4 => Should become 1.5
1.45 => Should become 1.5
1.466666666 => Should become 1.5
1.0 => Should remain 1.0
1.6 => Should become 2.0
```

The numbers need to always be rounded up.

I would be very grateful for any help on how to achieve this in C#!

Comment: It's not a duplicate because OP wants **up to closest .5**, not **the nearest .5**.

Comment: @Danny, care to elaborate on the difference?

Comment: Closest 0.5 to 0.1 is 0, he wants 0.5

Comment: So the title is wrong, it should say *next 0.5* (or something better) instead of *closest 0.5*. Then again, I do not see BugFinder's requirement listed anywhere in the question. Maybe the duplicate was legitimate after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of assuming that negative values are a valid input and that the desired behavior is to always round away from zero; all other valid answers will round towards zero in case of negative inputs.

The implementation is ugly but effective and easy to understand:

```
public static double Round(double d)
{
    var absoluteValue = Math.Abs(d);
    var integralPart = (long)absoluteValue;
    var decimalPart = absoluteValue - integralPart;
    var sign = Math.Sign(d);

    double roundedNumber;

    if (decimalPart > 0.5)
    {
        roundedNumber = integralPart + 1;
    }
    else if (decimalPart == 0)
    {
        roundedNumber = absoluteValue;
    }
    else
    {
        roundedNumber = integralPart + 0.5;
    }

    return sign * roundedNumber;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Negative values are indeed valid input, and therefore this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that casting from `double` to `long` can overflow, because `double`'s max value is very high: `1.79769313486232E+308`. [Math.Truncate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=netframework-4.7.2) could be used to calculate the integral part of the double.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want something like this:

```
Math.Ceiling(value / 0.5) * 0.5
```

Comment: Although the problem is unspecified, its reasonable to think that this solution will not work well with negative values as it rounds towards zero.

Comment: Which might be what the op wants, we don't know, it's unspecified ;-)

Comment: Nice and simple and works well with positive values, but it has to work with negative values as well - which, I know, I didn't specify. Thanks for your help, though :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var inputs = new [] { 1.4, 1.45, 1.466666666, 1.0, 1.6 };

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", input, Math.Ceiling(2.0 * input) / 2.0);
}
```

I get:

```
1.4 => 1.5
1.45 => 1.5
1.466666666 => 1.5
1 => 1
1.6 => 2
```

Answer (score -1):

To make the solution generic pass in the desired target:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static decimal RoundUp(this decimal num, decimal step = 0.5m)
    {
        /*
         * check the range of num and step
           according to your requirement
           e.g. num > 0 and step > 0
         */

        var result = Math.Floor(num);
        while (result < num)
        {
            result += step;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

//Usage

```
1.4m.RoundUp();   //1.5
1.0m.RoundUp();   //1.0
1.4m.RoundUp(0.2m);  //1.4
1.5m.RoundUp(0.2m);  //1.6
```

Comment: The OP has given clear inputs and outputs. Your answer should show how your code meets his requirement.

Answer (score -2):

This is the function you used to round the value

```
 public static decimal GetRoundValue(decimal value)
    {
        decimal half = 0.5M;
        int intValue = (int)value;

        decimal decimalValue = value - intValue;

        if (decimalValue > half) return intValue + half;
        else return (decimal)intValue;
    }
```

Comment: This only produces one of the 5 desired values.